# Excel VBA Error 462 With Internet Explorer

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer, navigation

I have this function:

```
Sub CreateDatabase()
    Dim ieNewPage As InternetExplorer, TableRows As Object, TableRow As Object
    Dim TableRowsSpecificOwner As Object, TableRowSpecificOwner As Object, TagNeeded As Object
    Set TableRows = GetData()
    Set ieNewPage = New InternetExplorer
    For Each TableRow In TableRows
        ieNewPage.navigate CStr(TableRow.href)
        Do While ieNewPage.ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        ieNewPage.Visible = True
        Set TableRowsSpecificOwner = ieNewPage.document.querySelectorAll("tr[class='puce_texte']")
        For Each TableRowSpecificOwner In TableRowsSpecificOwner
            If Excel.Application.IfError(Excel.Application.Search("France", TableRowSpecificOwner.innerText), -1) > 0 Then
                    Debug.Print TableRow.innerText
                    Debug.Print TableRowSpecificOwner.getElementsByTagName("a")(1).innerText
            End If
        Next
        Excel.Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    Next
End Sub
```

What it should to do is loop through the hrefs I get with the function `GetData()`, navigate the page, get some data and move to the next one.

This works for the first link but then I receive the error 462:

> The remote server does not exists or is unavailable.

The error is on this line:

```
ieNewPage.navigate CStr(TableRow.href)
```

How the heck do I solve this?

Comment: (TableRows contains <a> tags with a href inside and a textpart I also need)

Comment: It may be useful to know, what kind of object you receive after running the function `GetData()' or the function code itself.

Comment: @ZygD an example of a object in TableRows is something like this: `<a class="classname" href="link I need">Text info I also need </a>`

Comment: Run `typename(TableRows)` and tell us what type name do you get.

Comment: @ZygD I get: `DispHTMLElementCollection`

Comment: For me that line works properly. I guess that one of your `GetData()` results is something what you do not expect to be there (maybe it does not have a href inside). When you get the error, click *Debug* and try this line: `Debug.Print TableRow.outerhtml` so that you can see exactly which `TableRow` causes you the problem.

Comment: GetData() gives the correct output. At the first step of the loop everything works correctly, at the second step I get an error! The output is the same as the one I put in the comment above!

Comment: Side note; It is usually safer to extract contents from nodes and return from functions e.g. return a collection of hrefs rather than returning a collection of nodes dissociated from their parent if said parent is ie.document. And move  ieNewPage.Visible = True in front of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an article about this error: [Excel automation fails second time code runs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/178510/excel-automation-fails-second-time-code-runs), you could check it. The cause of the error is:

> Visual Basic has established a reference to Excel because of a line of code that calls an Excel object, method, or property without qualifying the element with an Excel object variable. Visual Basic does not release this reference until you end the program. This errant reference interferes with automation code when the code is run more than one time.

I think the error occurs because you didn't call the `Set` of `ieNewPage` for the second time. You could try to put `Set ieNewPage = New InternetExplorer` in the loop like this:

```
...    
Set TableRows = GetData()    
For Each TableRow In TableRows
    Set ieNewPage = New InternetExplorer
    ieNewPage.navigate CStr(TableRow.href)
    ...
Next
...
```